# Best method for migrating a huge (40GB) .sql MYSQL file to MSSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a roughly 40GB .sql MySQL file that needs to be imported to MSSQL. Best method for this?

I've tried SQLines studio, but it can't handle a file this large.

Comment: Do you mean a file full of `insert into` clauses or something else?

Comment: Import Wizard??

Comment: Yes it's full of DDL and DML statements. Inserts with hundreds of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two services i know of are Jira and Amazon DWM. I hope this link helps. https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/23/migrate-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql/